# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in xcode 10 and ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

Many People said that I have to run .xcworkspace behalf of .xcodeproj .but while I am trying to build or run my application then that's could not working properly and not helping to make .IPA for me.

Xcode version is 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you open the `.xcworkspace` not `.xcodeproj` and if you opening `.xcworkspace` then try to,

1. re-install pods `pod install` in the terminal
2. Clean build the project *(alt+product > clean build )*
3. Then run your project